# Assign Bode plots to Nyquist diagrams

Tags: transfer-function, bode-plot, control-theory, nyquist-plot

How do I assign the following Bode plots to their corresponding Nyquist diagram?
Can i tell the number of poles of the transfer function of the nyquist plot, by looking at w→infinity (from which of the four axis directions G(s) goes into the origin)?

I would have guessed, that:

- (1) is of the form \$ G(s) = -\frac{1}{(s+a)}\$ with \$ a>0 \$
- (2) is of the form \$ G(s) = \frac{1}{(s+a)}\$ with \$ a>0 \$
- (3) is of the form \$ G(s) = \frac{1}{(s+a)(s+b)}\$ with \$ a,b>0 \$
- (4) is of the form \$ G(s) = \frac{1}{(s)}\$ plus some other poles i dont know

---

- (a) is of the form \$ G(s) = \frac{1}{\frac{s}{2}+1} \$ or \$ \frac{2}{s+2} \$
- (b) is of the form \$ G(s) = \frac{1}{s(2s+1)} \$ or \$ \frac{0.5}{s(s+0.5)} \$
- (c) is of the form \$ G(s) = \frac{s}{\frac{s}{2}+1}  \$  or \$ \frac{2s}{s+2} \$
- (d) is of the form \$ G(s) = \frac{1}{(s+1)(\frac{s}{10}+1)} \$ or \$ \frac{10}{(s+1)(s+10)} \$

while (b) and (d) are missing the gain constant and thus (d) for example is stretched from 0 to 2 instead of 0 to 1. But thats not an issue, when all we want is assigning the bode and nyquist plots, right?

Also im bugged by (1) and (2) being identical (?)
I dont know how to put it in words but as theres only one half of the nyquist plot "circle" i assume we only go from 0 to infinity for the plot?
So a flip among the real axis indicates a minus in the gain constant, right?

If so, i can assume (c) has a negative gain constant, right?

---

My guess:

- (a) and (2)
- (b) and (4)
- (c) and (1) //c (bode) has a zero in the origin but 1 (nyquist) doesnt - what did i do wrong here? I guess the mistake is on the "nyquist side" analysis
- (d) and (3)

[image]

Comment: For assigning Bode to Nyquist diagrams you don't really have to think about transfer functions at all. It's a mathematical task: match the magnitude and phase form of a complex number to the real and imaginary part form.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are given both the magnitude and phase of the Bode Plots you can uniquely determine the pole/zero locations of the corresponding transfer function. In this case it is straight forward because the systems are all of first or second order. For systems of higher order though (for example 8th order) it might be impossible to do by eyesight alone.

The Bode Plot for a) has DC-gain of \$1\$, a phase shift of \$-45^\circ\$ at \$\omega = 2 \: \text{rad/s}\$, the slope of the gain is \$-20 \: \text{dB/dec}\$ (pole at -2) and this slope stays constant (no zeros). The transfer function must be \$H(s) = \frac{2}{s+2} \$.

The Bode Plot for b) has DC-gain of \$+\infty\$, the phase shift starts at \$-90^\circ\$, the slope of the gain is initially \$-20 \: \text{dB/dec}\$ (one pole at the origin). At \$\omega=2 \: \text{rad/s}\$ the phase shift is \$-135^\circ\$ and the slope of the gain is \$-40 \: \text{dB/dec}\$. There are no zeros. So currently, we have \$H(s) = \frac{b_0}{s(s+2)} \$. Additionally we know (it looks to me at least) that at \$\omega = 1 \: \text{rad/s}\$ the gain is \$1\$ (0 dB). The only value for \$b_0\$ that satisfies \$|H(j)| = 1\$ is \$b_0 = 2.244\$. The transfer function must be \$H(s) = \frac{2.24}{s(s+2)} \$.

Do you get the hang of it? If not, please ask.

The Nyquist Plot can be computed from the transfer function. This problem can actually be solved using heuristics without determining the transfer function.

**Response to comments**

> I do have a question about the calculation of b0
> though: How exaclty did you do that?

\$H(s) = \frac{b_0}{s(s+2)} \: \Rightarrow |H(j\omega)| = \bigg|\frac{b_0}{(j\omega)^2+2j\omega}\bigg| = \frac{\sqrt{b_0^2}}{\sqrt{(\omega^2)^2+(2\omega)^2}} = \frac{b_0}{\sqrt{(\omega^2)^2+(2\omega)^2}}\$, because \$b_0 > 0 \: \land \: b_0 \in \mathbb{R} \$.

At \$\omega = 1 \: \text{rad/s}\$ we have \$|H(j)| = 1\$, so:

$$|H(j)| = 1 = \frac{b_0}{\sqrt{1+2^2}} \Leftrightarrow$$

$$b_0 = \sqrt{5} \approx 2.24 $$

> Also, i do find myself having trouble with nyquist plot (1) and (2).

Nyquist Plot 1) starts (\$\omega=0\$) at the origin, hence the distance to the origin is zero (\$-\infty \: \text{dB}\$), and it ends (\$\omega \to \infty\$) at a unit distance from the origin (\$0 \: \text{dB}\$) with a phase shift of \$0^\circ\$. So this can only belong to Bode Plot c).

Nyquist Plot 2) starts (\$\omega=0\$) at a unit distance from the origin (\$0 \: \text{dB}\$) and \$0^\circ\$ phase shift. As frequency increases (\$\omega \to \infty\$), the distance to the origin goes towards zero (\$-\infty \: \text{dB}\$) and the phase shift goes towards \$-90^\circ\$. It can only be Bode Plot a).

Comment: Thank you very much, that is a neat explanation! I do have a question about the calculation of \$ b_0\$ though: How exaclty did you do that? Isnt it a lot of work to solve \$  | H(j)| = 1 \$, since you have to split \$  H(wj) \$ into real and imaginary parts? Also, i do find myself having trouble with nyquist plot (1) and (2). I assume the plots go from \$ w=0 \$ to \$ w=infinity \$ instead of the \$ w=-infinity \$ to \$ w=infinity \$ i am used to? What difference between \$ G_1(s) \$ and \$ G_2(s) \$ flips the plot along the real axis and changes the arrow direction?

Comment: @insertRandomName Have a look at the update in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response and kind help! Why does \$ b_0 \$ has to be greater than zero? Could it be that \$ b_0 \$ is negative only if the phase starts at 180 degrees? And just to be sure: \$ G_c (s) = \frac{c_0*s}{s+2} \$, right? This explains the behaviour of the nyquist plot 1. I misunderstood that the origin always corresponds to \$ w → infinity \$ and 1 or -1 to \$ w = 0  \$ but of course thats not the case. I just was not aware of the arrow indicating increasing \$ w \$. Thanks so much, that cleared a lot of stuff i assumed to know for sure.

Comment: @insertRandomName Exactly! \$b_0>0\$ because the DC-gain is positive (0°) and not negative (\$\pm\$180°). Also correct, system c) has a zero at the origin and a pole at -2. And yes, the direction of the arrow in the Nyquist Plot denotes the direction of the graph as the frequency increases.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Feel free to look at my other question regarding nyquist plots and transfer functions.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I assign the following Bode plots to their corresponding Nyquist diagram?

As stated by Lars Henkeln in a comment:

> For assigning Bode to Nyquist diagrams you don't really have to think about transfer functions at all. It's a mathematical task: match the magnitude and phase form of a complex number to the real and imaginary part form.

Let \$A(\omega)\$ be the amplitude at \$\omega\$, and let \$\phi(\omega)\$ be the phase angle.

From inspection alone,

for Nyquist plot 1:

$$A(0) = 0$$
$$\phi(0) = 90^\circ$$
(the plot leaves the origin in the \$90^\circ\$ direction!)
$$A(\infty) = 1$$
$$\phi(\infty) = 0^\circ$$

this corresponds with Bode plot (c).

---

For Nyquist plot 2:

$$A(0) = 1$$
$$\phi(0) = 0^\circ$$
$$A(\infty) = 0$$
$$\phi(\infty) = -90^\circ$$
(the plot arrives at the origin from the \$-90^\circ\$ direction)

this corresponds with Bode plot (a).

---

For Nyquist plot 3:

$$A(0) = 1$$
$$\phi(0) = 0^\circ$$
$$A(\infty) = 0$$
$$\phi(\infty) = -180^\circ$$
(the plot arrives at the origin from the \$-180^\circ\$ direction. It is a little hard to see. It actually looks to me more like \$-135^\circ\$, but that doesn't correspond to an available option.)

this corresponds with Bode plot (d).

---

For Nyquist plot 4:

$$A(0) = \infty$$
$$\phi(0) = -90^\circ$$
$$A(\infty) = 0$$
$$\phi(\infty) = -180^\circ$$

This corresponds with Bode plot (b).

---

> Also im bugged by (1) and (2) being identical (?)

Notice the arrowhead on the plots in the Nyquist diagrams. (1) and (2) have opposite start and end points.